# Create new incremental grouping column based on if logic from group, rank, and category columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to sum totals together that goes beyond a basic "group by" or "case" statement.

Here's an example datasets:

```
Amt Cust_id Ranking PlanType
10  1       1       Term
6   1       2       Variable
8   1       3       Variable
7   1       4       Variable
12  1       5       Term
6   1       6       Variable
10  1       7       Variable
```

The objective is to return the max sum where the plan type is 'Variable' and 
the Ranking numbers are adjacent to each other.

So the answer to the example would be the sum of rows 2-4 which returns 21.
The answer is not the sum of all variable plan types, because row 5 is a 'Term' which breaks it apart.

So I'd like to end with a dataset like below to handle multiple groups of customers:

```
Amt Cust_ID
21  1
30  2 
45  3
```

Here's where I'm stuck which returns wrong answer:

```
Create Table #tb (Amt INT, Cust_id TINYINT, Ranking INT, PlanType 
VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO #tb
VALUES (10,1,1,'Term'),
    (6,1,2,'Variable'),
    (8,1,3,'Variable'),
    (7,1,4,'Variable'),
    (12,1,5,'Term'),
    (6,1,6,'Variable'),
    (10,1,7,'Variable'),

    (10,2,1,'Term'),
    (6,2,2,'Variable'),
    (7,2,4,'Variable'),
    (12,2,5,'Term'),
    (6,2,6,'Variable'),
    (50,2,7,'Variable')

select  
    ( SELECT SUM(Amt) FROM #tb as t2
      WHERE t2.Cust_ID=t1.Cust_ID AND t2.Ranking<=t1.Ranking AND 
      t2.PlanType='Variable') RollingAmt

,Cust_ID, Ranking, Amt, PlanType
from #tb as t1
order by Cust_ID, Ranking
```

The query runs a rolling sum ordered by "Ranking" where PlanType = 'Variable'. Unfortunately it runs a rolling sum of all "Variable"'s together. I need it to not do that.
If it runs into a PlanType "Term" it needs to start over its sum within each group.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to do this you need to use a gaps-and-islands technique to generate a "group id" based on consecutive runs of the same PlanType, then you can sum and sort based on that new group id.

Try this:

```
DECLARE @data TABLE (Amt INT, Cust_id TINYINT, Ranking INT, PlanType VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO @data
VALUES (10,1,1,'Term'),
        (6,1,2,'Variable'),
        (8,1,3,'Variable'),
        (7,1,4,'Variable'),
        (12,1,5,'Term'),
        (6,1,6,'Variable'),
        (10,1,7,'Variable'),

        (10,2,1,'Term'),
        (6,2,2,'Variable'),
        (7,2,4,'Variable'),
        (12,2,5,'Term'),
        (6,2,6,'Variable'),
        (50,2,7,'Variable')

;WITH X AS
(
    SELECT *, 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Cust_id,PlanType ORDER BY Ranking)
            - ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Cust_id ORDER BY Ranking) groupID /* Assign a groupID to consecutive runs of PlanTypes by Cust_id */
    FROM @data
), Y AS
    (
        SELECT *, SUM(Amt) OVER(PARTITION BY Cust_id,groupID) AS AmtSum /* Sum Amt by Cust/groupID */
        FROM X
        WHERE PlanType='Variable'
    ), Z AS
        (
            SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Cust_id ORDER BY AmtSum DESC) AS RN /* Assign a row number (1) to highest AmtSum by Cust */
            FROM Y
        )

SELECT AmtSum, Cust_id
FROM Z
WHERE RN=1 /* Only select RN=1 to get highest value by cust_id/groupId */
```

If you are curious about how this all works, you can comment the last `SELECT` and do `SELECT * FROM X` then `SELECT * FROM Y` etc, to see what each step does along the way; but only one `SELECT` can follow the entire CTE structure.